# In Java, is it better to avoid explicitly using database column names, data types etc?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it considered better practice to avoid explicitly using (hardcoding) database column headers, data types etc. when fetching results from a database table? What I'm getting at is - is it better to pretend like I know absolutely nothing about the way the database is structured and let the program work that out (thus making it longer and more complicated), or is it perfectly fine to just use it directly in the code (or possibly list most information as constants at the top of the class)?

For example, there are these two ways of retrieving data from a table.

The simple way being:

```
ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Blob> profilePictures = new ArrayList<>();

// this method presumes that there are columns named user_name and 
// profile_picture and that they hold string and blob values
// respectively

while(resultSet.next()) {
    userNames.add(resultSet.getString("user_name"));
    profilePictures.add(resultSet.getBlob("profile_picture"));
}
```

... and the other way being:

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();

ArrayList<String> columnHeaders = new ArrayList<>();

// doesn't know what the column headers are
for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    columnHeaders.add(meta.getColumnName(i));
}

ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<columnHeaders.size(); i++) {
    data.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
}

for(int i=0; resultSet.next(); i++) {
    for (String header : columnHeaders) {
        // no presuming what the data type will be
        int type = meta.getColumnType(i);
        if(type == Types.VARCHAR) {
             data.get(i).add(resultSet.getString(header));
         } else if(type == Types.BLOB) {
            data.get(i).add(resultSet.getBlob(header));
         }
    }
}
```

The first way is short and sweet, but the other way feels...smarter(?).

Is there justifiable reason for doing things the hard way, or am I just overcomplicating things?

Comment: The answer would depend greatly on what you're trying to achieve. From my own personal experience, no, but kind a, yes.  A lot of API's (like hibernate) deal with mapping tables/columns to objects, so you must know, at some point, what the table/column names are, but you want to reduce the amount of times you might access that information directly, so if the table/column name changes you're not running throughout the code trying to find it

Comment: The major difference between your two code-snippets is not in what they assume about the columns, but in the data structures they return. Both do a poor job, but the first one is significantly worse.

Comment: Why is the first one worse and what are the major flaws which mean they do a poor job?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no set rule as to which approach is better, it varies from case to case. If you have a table with two columns only, then it makes sense to hard code the column names, without going through the hassle of iterating through the loop.

But if you have a table with suppose 40 columns, then the code becomes ugly/unreadable with hard coded values, in that case you may opt-in for the iterative approach

Answer (score -1):

Unless you're writing a piece of generic middleware you can't avoid it. At some point in any application you will have to store a database column value into a language variable, or *vice versa*, and at that point you will need to know the column name and write it into your code.